# How to get current selected node (TREEVIEW)?

Tags: c#

If I use

```
MessageBox.Show(treeView1.SelectedNode.ToString());
```

the result is `TreeNode: Bob`.

How do I just get `Bob` without the `TreeNode`?

Comment: Do you use WPF, WinForms or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close:

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Name
```

You may want to check if selected node is null too.